# How to update an Elasticsearch document in NEST2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, elasticsearch, nest

I have ported my code to NEST 2.0 and Elasticsearch 2.0

I need to find a way to update a document already stored into ES2

I was using the [partial object technique](https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/update.html):

```
        elastic.Update<myDocumentType, myPartialDocumentType>(u => u
            .Index(myIndexName)
            .Id(id)
            .Doc(
                new myPartialDocumentType()
                {
                    // set the fields to update here
                })
            .Refresh());
```

How to do the same thing using NEST2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way how you are passing document id changed a bit.

Looks like follow today:

```
var updateResponse = client.Update<Document, DocumentPartial>(1, descriptor => descriptor
        .Doc(new DocumentPartial
        {
            Title = "new title"
        }));
```

or

```
var updateResponse = client.Update<Document, DocumentPartial>(DocumentPath<Document>.Id(1), descriptor => descriptor
    .Doc(new DocumentPartial
    {
        Title = "new title"
    }));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you Rob, expect a huge increase on your reputation counter the next week. guarantee ;-) Looks like you are the only one to know how to properly use the newest NEST2 library

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini We've been at Elasticon this past week :)

Comment: thx. not working for me. and their documentation is severely lacking yet again. also no way to perform a search of the documentation that i see. oh - it looks like the signature of that method has changed a bit since this. ElasticLowLowLevelClient.Update<T>(string index, string type, string id, PostData<object> body, [Func...])