# ElasticSearch Update using Nest C# Error "is not a delegate type"

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

When trying to use [NEST](https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/update.html) sample code for updating with my product class

```
var node = new Uri(Host);

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
    node
);

settings.DefaultIndex("my-application");

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);    

var response = client.Update<Product>(u => u
                        .Id(1)
                        .Script("ctx._source.country = country")
                        .Params(p => p
                            .Add("country", "United States")
                            )
                        .RetryOnConflict(3)
                        .Refresh()
                        );

public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public List<PriceBand> PriceList { get; set; }
}

public class PriceBand
{
    public int CurrencyID { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double RRP { get; set; }
}
```

I recieve the error

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'Nest.IUpdateRequest`<Product,Product>`' because it is not a delegate
>   type

on the first lambda expression (u => u) The .cs file (I'm run the call on the .cs part of an .aspx webpage) is using:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
```

Which most posts suggest to add. Any suggestions on how to fix this error or how to update using NEST?

*Note that the Search method is working correctly.

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Product>(s => s
                        .From(0)
                        .Size(10)
                        .Query(q => q
                        .Fuzzy(fz => fz
                            .Field(f => f.Description)
                            .Value("marti")
                            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))
                        )));
```

***UPDATE***
Thanks to Rob for the info, the documentation is out of date.

The updated method is:

```
var updateResponse = client.Update<Document, DocumentPartial>(1, descriptor => descriptor
        .Doc(new DocumentPartial
        {
            Title = "new title"
        }));
```

[Robs original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630189/how-to-update-an-elasticsearch-document-in-nest2/35632211#35632211)

Comment: Try to use ElasticClient instead of ElasticsearchClient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Elasticsearch NEST cannot convert lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196256/c-sharp-elasticsearch-nest-cannot-convert-lambda-expression)

Comment: @MUG4N Hi, the client is already set to var client = new ElasticClient(settings); i'll add the client set-up to the question.

Comment: What version of NEST and elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: `Update` signature changed a little bit in NEST 2.x. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630189/how-to-update-an-elasticsearch-document-in-nest2/35632211#35632211) answer for help :)

Comment: Thank you very much Rob, I'm new to ElasticSearch so didn't realise the documentation is for an older version. (which explains all the trouble I keep running in to.)

Comment: @BenClose new docs will be dropping *really* soon; in the meantime, feel free to post questions on stackoverflow, on github (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues) and discuss (https://discuss.elastic.co/c/elasticsearch)