# Partial update elastic search NEST 2.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, updates, nest

how can partial update a record in using NEST2?

I'm looking for an analog request:
    POST /erection/shop/1/_update
    {"doc": {"new":"0"}}

**without recreating** a new record. unfortunately I did not find anything about the updates in www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index.html

**UPDATE:**

```
var updateResponse = es.Current.Update<MyDocument, MyDocument>   (DocumentPath<MyDocument>.Id(2), descriptor => descriptor
     .Doc(new MyDocument
     {
         name = "new name"
     }));
```

I run this code, but it is fully updated the whole document.

result https://gyazo.com/2fdae851bb8bc445f6e8e58abb2f0e3b
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will find an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630189/how-to-update-an-elasticsearch-document-in-nest2/35632211#35632211).

Comment: thx for the answer, but i do not understand which namespace have **DocumentPartial** and **DocumentPath**. i try to use your code, but i'm having an error.  
            `var updateResponse = es.Current.Update<Document, MyDocument>(descriptor => descriptor
                .Id(1)
                .Doc(new MyDocument
                {
                    name = "qwerty"
                }));`
i tried to use this code, but it update all document, and leave all the fields empty except for "name"

Comment: May you post your full example?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/8fdb6de621bd1880f1ca51b443953bcf - screenshot with my code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use anonymous object or another class with properties that you want update. try this code:

```
var updateResponse = es.Current.Update<MyDocument, object>(1, descriptor => descriptor
            .Doc(new { name = "new name" }));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, Mohammad
this is exactly what I needed

Comment: pls tick answer if true answer for other user

Comment: +1 for anonymous type. I'd probably use the same property name casing as the type being updated - the serialized casing in json will match with whatever serializer settings are being used.

Comment: @Russ Cam: Do not understand your question! Please explain further or give an example

Comment: @MohammadAkbari - I mean, using `new { Name = "new name" }` for the anonymous type instead of `new { name = "new name" }` and let the `.DefaultFieldNameInferrer()` on connection settings take care of casing the property name

Comment: How can I update a field `Name` using the anonymous type?
For me using `new { Name = "new name" }`  result on a new field `"name":"new name"`.